# Anime where a villain tries to kill the heroes by placing them in a giant centrifuge

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

I've only watched one scene from this anime. Although it is an anime, that's not to imply that it is or isn't from Japan. In the scene, the bad guy tries to kill the protagonists by restraining them and placing them inside a centrifuge, then setting the rotation rate high enough to be lethal. The protagonists escape because one of them has a very powerful laser disguised as a lipstick, which he/she uses to free them.

After the protagonists escape, they see some aircraft that look like fighter jets taking off, and shoot them down using what I think are handheld weapons of some kind, perhaps plasma cannons?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MakeupWeapon - One of these, perhaps?

Comment: By centrifuge do you mean a [training centrifuge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJyBIUNlY2M) or a [rotor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQP8aH37i9I)?

Comment: @user73910 - In roughly which year did you watch this anime? Was it a movie or an episode from a series? Can you describe the appearance of any of the characters?

Comment: In some ways it sounds like Totally Spies - they *did* have a lipstick laser, and the show had (IMO) anime-style art but wasn't actually from Japan. But I've checked their wiki and I can't find anything about them using it to escape a centrifuge trap.

Comment: @Valorum It was a training centrifuge.

Comment: @user73910 - and was it one-armed or two-armed (with a counterweight at the other end)?

Comment: And if he had the ability to put them into said centrifuge, is there a reason he did so (e.g. as opposed to just shooting them in the head)?

Comment: The lipstick laser immediately makes me think of SheZow, who had one as her/his signature weapon.  Can't speak to a particular episode (I just saw bits in the background when my child was watching it), but it sounds like the kind of over-the-top sequence that would happen in the show.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/123/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked the question on Reddit and was given the suggestion both there and in the comments of this question that it could be an episode from Totally Spies, so I looked up "Totally Spies centrifuge scene" on Google and was taken to a Youtube link showing Episode 15 of Season 2. It definitely matches my recollection.

Centrifuge trap:
[image: A scene depicting several characters in a room that is made to look slightly futuristic because of its blue hue. It's a round shaped room with a centrifuge, in which the 3 protagonists of Totally Spies, Sam, Clover and Alex, are locked in. They are faced by the evil lady dressed in some white outfit and her 2 security guards in a suit. The evil lady is probably explaining her plan and how she intends to get rid of the spies with the centrifuge, as every evil characters do in each Totally Spies episode.]

Using a laser lipstick to escape:

[image: Sam, Clover and Alex still in the centrifuge, each with a rope around their torso tying them up. Both Sam and Clover have their eyes closed as Alex is cutting through the centrifuge's glass with a laser lipstick, a signature gadget of Totally Spies. Sam is the only one to be in her spy outfit with a pink backpack, whereas Clover and Alex are in their daily life outfits.]

Using a handheld weapon to destroy some fighter jets:

[image: The scene depicts a military style aircraft in a long corridor; probably a take off corridor for the plane. Several rockets can be seen flying toward the screen and the plane; possibly shot by someone in the background to prevent the plane from taking off.]